# How to show image from jtable in jlabel?

Tags: java, user-interface, binding, jtable, tablemodel

Is there a way to show photo from `jtable` that is bind with mysql on `jlabel` when selected? I use this code to show text in `texfield`:

```
int selectedrow=jTable1.getSelectedRow();

TableModel model=(TableModel)jTable1.getModel();
jTextField7.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 0).toString());
jTextField6.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 1).toString());
jTextField5.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 2).toString());

jTextField1.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 3).toString());
jTextField2.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 4).toString());
jTextField4.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 5).toString());
jTextField3.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 6).toString());
jTextField8.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 7).toString());
jTextField9.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 8).toString());
```

I tried adding this but gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to javax.swing.ImageIcon`

```
ImageIcon image=(ImageIcon) model.getValueAt(selectedrow,9);
Image image2=image.getImage().getScaledInstance(jLabel10.getWidth(),jLabel10.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIcon image3=new ImageIcon(image2);
jLabel10.setIcon(image3);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Please, I edited your question but it still needs better formatting to understand it

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question is not clear to me because information is partial. As @GrayCygnus suggested post [mcve]